# I'm working with a current_timestamp. What function do I need to find out "one day from now"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

Using MySQL, i have a current timestamp that looks like this:

```
2011-11-01 10:34:24
```

Is there a PHP function that I could use to "check against" this time? I want to know if this time is more than a day old from "now".

Edit: Solution (that works for my usecase)

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// date voted
$date_voted = '2011-09-01 10:34:24'; 

// +24
$future_time = ( strtotime($date_voted) ) + 86400;

// current time
$curr_time = time(); 

if ( $curr_time < $future_time ) { 
    echo "You can't vote just yet!\n\n";
} else if ( $curr_time >= $future_time ) { 
    echo "Vote counted!\n\n"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$some_date = strtotime('2011-11-01 10:34:24');
$now = time();
$seconds_diff = $now - $some_date;
$days = $seconds_diff / 86400;
echo $days;
```

Answer (score 3):

With MySql you could try:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Good point. But sometimes you want retrieve the row and validate it in your application to react on specific circumstances. (instead of not fetching it and have no chance to validate it)

Comment: I think this is the better approach as it's already built into MySQL so the wheel doesn't need to be re-invented at the app layer.